# Distribution of $N(a,1)/(\chi^2/k)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

A $N(0,1)/(\chi^2/k)$ variable is distributed over a $t$-distribution with $k$ df.

What is an $N(a,1)/(\chi^2/k)$ variable ( $a \neq 0$) distributed as?

And am I correct in saying that the power of a $t$-test -

$\operatorname{Pr}((X - h)/(s^2/n) > T$ given that true mean = $\mu$),  $h$ = hypothesis mean and $\mu$ = $h$ + *q*.

is determined by the above distribution? That is, 
is $((X-h)-\mu)/(s^2/n)$ an $N(a,1)/(\chi^2/k)$ variable?

Comment: Please use LaTeX for readability.

Comment: Thanks for edit. Really sorry- I was in a hurry and I haven't yet worked out how to use it. Won't happen again.

Comment: Good observation. That's why the noncentral t distribution arise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution

Comment: Thanks! So the answer will be in the Wiki page?

Comment: Did you forget square root in denominator?

Comment: Yes- forgot that. I'll get better at this "Maths on computer thing.." ;)